# Google Analytics setup for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-ga

I have managed to set up Google Analytics for my React application with the [ReactGA library](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) so it will send the pageview to analytics when the user navigates around.

#### The problem

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not sending any analytics to google on the initial page load, since the `history.listen` method only fires when the location changes.

#### My setup

In the root of my project, I initialize the connection:

```js
const history = require("history").createBrowserHistory;
import { Router } from "react-router-dom"

ReactGA.initialize(envConstants.ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID);

const MyApp = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <MyRoutes /> 
  </Router>
)
```

Since I only want to see which routes the users are on I have this in my router:

```js
const MyRoutes = props => {
  props.history.listen(location => {
    // won't see this on initial load, but navigating to another route will give me this
    console.log("LISTENING") 
  })

  return (...)
}
```

So I wonder how I can come around this and send the first/ initial pageview when a user comes to my site. I believe I cannot achieve this with the `history.listen` method. So, I guess we have to add some other functionality that I'm not too sure of.

I appreciate all the help I can get with this. And if there's something unclear, please let me know.

Thanks for reading and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that history listen is not called on initial page load since it's only called when the location changes. Try something like the following

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

const trackPageView = location => {
  ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
};

const initGa = history => {
  ReactGA.initialize('UA-XXXXXX-X', {
    debug: true
  });
  trackPageView(history.location);
  history.listen(trackPageView);
};

const history = createHistory();
initGa(history);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={history}>
      <Layout />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```